# session variable lost between pages

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have 3 .php files:

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['comp_id']))
{
    require_once 'scan_albums.php';
}
else
{
    require_once 'login.php';
}

echo "SESSION['comp_id']=" .$_SESSION['comp_id'];
?>
```

scan_ablums.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["comp_id"]))
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
//...
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['comp_id']))
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
$_SESSION['comp_id'] = 3;
?>
```

I invoke login.php via ajax:

```
$.ajax(
{
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'login.php',
  data: {'login': login, 'password': hpass},
  success: function(data)
  {
    console.log("ajax: [comp_id]=" + data + "\n");
    window.location = "index.php";
  }
});
```

After redirect to my index.php $_SESSION['comp_id'] is empty. What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that these pages are in iframe app in social network. Maybe this is the problem?

EDIT: Problem is definitely in iframe. Sessions are fine ob my local machine. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You must call session_start(); at the beginning of every page that uses the session.

Comment: Yes, I did that. All i get is warnings that session is already started. Variable is still empty though.

Comment: `login.php` and `scan_albums.php` don't have `session_start()`

Comment: @Mike beat me by ~12 seconds!

Comment: Session is already started in index.php. However i mean that nothing changes even when i add session_start() to each of file. Php only give me warnings about it's already started. Variable is still empty.

Comment: Added session_start() to each file to clear that up. $_SESSION['comp_id'] is an empty string.

Comment: don't forget to include `session_write_close()` after you've written your data to the session variable as this could have negative implications if not used in a multiuser environment. This stops the session file from locking up if two or more users try to write data to session variables.

Answer (score 2):

http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Try calling session_write_close(); after you do the "login"

Check the session_id in the pages to see if it's all equal.

Also see:

> When session.use_trans_sid is enabled, the session_start() function
>   will register an internal output handler for URL rewriting.

In session_start

Comment: I found that sessions aren't stored because browser security policies. Browsers just won't let to set session variables in iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Check with your hosting provider about the details of their PHP configuration, specifically how it handles *session* data.

Ideally compare their php.ini configuration with your local (working) configuration. Check the *session* section.